# Download links in answers - best way to handle this?

Tags: discussion

Related, but not really:

[Use of download links in answers](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1711/use-of-download-links-in-answers)

Ok, now that I've got that out of the way, it was recently posted in the chatroom that folks have a tendency to post answers with links to random blog sites/download sites, and there's no way to make sure that is' really what they're downloading, as opposed to a trojan or something.

What is the best way to handle this? I floated the idea of having a launchpad project just for Ask Ubuntu, and doing file uploads *that* way, but that could get messy. Ideas?

Comment: It's inevitable that people will post links to random downloads. Warnings should always be prefixed with a warning prior to use.

Answer (score 3):

This is a step that involves some extra effort from you but it can help to improve the trust a user has when downloading something.

If you write an answer that links to a file then make sure to also post a MD5 hash of that file so people can check if it is the same file or if it is *intact*.

When posting a link to an external site I generally also mention where the link will take the user to.

Example:

> Read this [article](http://somesite.com/somearticle) on [Somesite.com](http://somesite.com).

There is not much more you can do.